# Magento PWA show custom product attribute in details page

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, pwa, pwa-studio

I am trying to modify product details page on **Magento PWA Studio**. I have a custom **attribute(text-editor type)**, and I have some html there. When I am trying to call that attribute it comes as string instead of html. Like image src in that html provided as media path, it does not convert that as actual path instead it showing the media path directly(see below).[image]

**Same html is working fine when I put that in description/short_description. Below is my graphql query-**

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
export const GET_PRODUCT_SHORT_DESCRIPTION = gql`
query getProductShortDescription($urlKey: String!) {
    products(filter: { url_key: { eq: $urlKey } }) {
        items {
            id,
            uid,
            url_key,
            short_description {
                html
            },
            top_banner_image
        }
    }
}`;
```

Now I understand that my html working in short_description because in graphql query **short_description** has sub selection **html** so I tried to use that in my custom attribute **top_banner_image** but getting bellow error in console-

> Message: Field "top_banner_image" of type "String" must not have a sub selection

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how can I get that attributes value as html as similar like short_description?
Thanks

Comment: Please check the attribute type, and compare it with the short description you'll get an Idea about that.

Comment: I did check it already and make both attribute similar, but still not working

Comment: It looks like your attribute is defined as a string where as description and short description are defined as `ComplexTextValue` - As for where you define this I'm not sure :(

Comment: This is the schema for short_description, I think you need to do something similar? `short_description: ComplexTextValue @doc(description: "A short description of the product. Its use depends on the theme.") @resolver(class: "\\Magento\\CatalogGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\ProductComplexTextAttribute")` - vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls line 97

Comment: @BenCrook yes, you are right about that. I made the attribute similar to short description in terms of settings but that didn't change anything. I will keep checking how can I make it complextextvalue. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 1):

You can display it like this, and change your code according to your need, this is just an example.

```
<img src="' . $this->getUrl('media/') . $post->getImage() . '" width="' . $wid . '" height="' . $hei . '" >
```

Comment: It's not phtml. I have to pul that html in product attribute

Answer (score 1):

VendorName/Modulename/etc/schema.graphqls

```
interface ProductInterface {
        wysiwyngattributename: String @resolver(class: "VendorName\\Modulename\\Model\\Resolver\\ProductWysiwygAttribute")
    }
```

VendorName\Modulename\Model\Resolver\ProductWysiwygAttribute.php
<?php

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\Modulename\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output as OutputHelper;

/**
 * Resolve attributes where HTML content is allowed
 */
class ProductWysiwygAttribute implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var OutputHelper
     */
    private $outputHelper;

    /**
     * @param OutputHelper $outputHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        OutputHelper $outputHelper
    ) {
        $this->outputHelper = $outputHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ): string {
        if (!isset($value['model'])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('"model" value should be specified'));
        }

        /* @var $product Product */
        $product = $value['model'];
        $fieldName = $field->getName();
        $renderedValue = $this->outputHelper->productAttribute($product, $product->getData($fieldName), $fieldName);

        return $renderedValue ?? '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you fix it? I have the same issue.

Comment: I haven't. If you got any solution please let me know